# Post JSON array using strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, strong-parameters

How can I allow a JSON array POST to my API endpoint through strong parameters?

Assuming I have the following JSON:

`{
    "objects": [
        {
            "attr1": "hi",
            "attr2": "hi2"
        },
        {
            "attr1": "hi",
            "attr2": "hi2"
        }
    ]
}`

How can I get Rails to fit this into its params? I currently get an obscure `Unprocessed Entity` response when I post the request to my create action.

I have tried both `params.require(:objects)` and `params.require(objects: [])`, to no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full parameter string that you are sending to rails?  The json object will need to be properly converted into a parameter string:  once this is done rails should be able to process it fine, even if it's a nested object like this.

Comment: I thought rails would figure that out from the accept or the content-type header?

Comment: As a matter of fact I had a typo in the content-type header. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a silly typo in my Content-Type header.